# Unable to connect to localhost from android device

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, localhost, ionic-framework

Disclaimer : I am aware that there are a large number of similar-sounding questions to this one. But  responses to those haven't helped me.

I have connected my android device to my development machine with a USB cable and I am running a server on my machine (ionic/cordova livereload and dev server.)  This server is at port 8100 and the livereload is at 35729.
When running the application with livereload turned on, the app did not run and was just a blank screen. I decided to hit the dev server through my phone's browser and I entered the IP address of the dev machine on the browser and the connection keeps timing out. Basically, I am just not able to connect localhost through my android device.

The following are things I have tried based on responses to a similar question :

1. Both the dev machine and device are on the same wifi.
2. I got the IP address of the dev machine by running an `ipconfig` command.

I am not sure why this is happening and I have spent precious hours trying to figure this out. Can anyone please help. I will be able to provide more information and update the question as requested.

Comment: Possibly need to forward ports or look at your firewall? Going through a router always opens up new issues, and I am no network guru... just trying to help :P

Comment: @zgc7009 I need all the help I can :) When you mean forward ports, what do you mean? Regarding firewall, I set up an inbound rule but I am not even sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: Sometimes you have to explicitly tell your router that you want to open a port up. By default routers don't like to open up ports that it doesn't know that you want to access to try to keep your network locked down/secure. http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

Comment: Are you able to configure the port for livereload? If so, try something more standard like 8080 or 8888

Comment: @srinivas.naik : **"I have connected my android device to my development machine"** - What does that mean? How exactly have you "connected" your device to your dev machine?

Comment: oh my bad... through the usb cable.

Comment: your usage of localhost and usb cable is just confusing the situation. localhost always maps to 127.0.0.1 which is not route-able over ethernet. usb cable is not routing tcp/ip either. From a troubleshooting point of view -  1) check network connectivity between the two wifi ip addresses using ping and traceroute; 2) check that your server is listening to the wifi ip address rather than localhost; 3) you may want to try from another notebook then try from the mobile device.